# Why do defect energy states appear only in the band-gap?

Tags: solid-state-physics, density-of-states

It has been shown that defects (due to doping for example) in a semiconductor cause a "tail" to appear in the density of states.
Why do these states appear in the bandgap,and how is the energy they "sit at" determined ?

Also, what would happen to the DOS of a metal with a huge (as in > 10% the concentration of atoms for example) number of defects ?

Comment: Doping (at reasonable levels, not degenerate) may lead to specific states (not a tail) in the gap. Nothing rules out them having states inside existing bands, although you'd have to calculate where the are since they would be swamped by the normal states. As for what a "huge" number of defects might look like, compare crystal silicon to amorphous silicon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to know at what energy the state will be ? I often see doping diagrams with the n- dopants right below the conduction band for example, but I've never seen a precise value, or why they are supposed to be in this zone in particular.

Comment: A good semiconductor physics book such as Sze will have a nice graph with a wide range of known states in the gap with positions. Now, in general, if the doping level is not near a band edge it is thought of more as a trap state since it will not be thermally activated.